# Find document, then find entry within array and remove it from the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In Node and Mongoose, I'd like to remove an object from an array in a document. The structure is like this.

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId,
    title: String,
    tags: [
        { text: String },
        { text: String }
    ]
}
```

I will look up an item by it's `_id`, but then I want to look within the tags for a certain `String` and remove that from the array.

Comment: And? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively want to [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) the document and use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator with a query matching the matching value under `"tags.tag"`:

```
Model.update(
    { "_id": docId, "tags.tag": "mytag" },
    { "$pull": { "tags": { "tag": "mytag" } },
    function(err,numAffected) {

    }
)
```